# Prove that the sum of minimum edge cover and maximum matching is the vertex count

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Given a connected graph, how can we prove that the number of edge of its minimum edge cover plus its maximum matching is equal to the number of vertices?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given a graph $G$, let $\rho^*$ and $m^*$ denote the minimum edge cover and the maximum matching of $G$ respectively. We prove $|\rho^*| + |m^*| \leq n$ and $|\rho^*| + |m^*| \geq n$ in order below, where $n$ is the # of vertices in $G$.

- $|\rho^*| + |m^*| \leq n$

Let $S$ be the set of vertices that are not contained in $m^*$. It is easy to see that $S$ is an independent set of $G$; otherwise, we can further enlarge $m^*$, contradicting the fact that $m^*$ is a max matching. We construct an edge cover $\rho'$ of $G$ by adding one of $v$'s adjacent edges to $\rho'$ for each $v \in S$ and adding all edges in $m^*$ to $\rho'$. The resulting $\rho'$ would cover all vertices in $G$ and $|\rho'| = |m^*| + |S|$.
Therefore,
$$
|m^*| + |\rho^*| \leq |m^*| + |\rho'| = 2|m^*| + |S| = n \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$

- $|\rho^*| + |m^*| \geq n$

If $\rho^*$ is a minimum edge cover, then the edges in $\rho^*$ do not contain a path of length of more than $2$. This is because if a path of length of $>2$ exists, we can remove one of intermediate edges to shrink $\rho^*$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, the connected components of $\rho^*$ are all star graphs. Denote the # of connected components in $\rho^*$ as $c$ and the components as $C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_c$. We have
$$
|V(C_1)| + |V(C_2)| + \cdots + |V(C_c)| = n
$$
and
$$
|E(C_1)| + |E(C_2)| + \cdots + |E(C_c)| = |\rho^*|
$$
For a star graph, the # of edges is always $1$ less than the # of vertices; i.e., $|E(C_i)| = |V(C_i)| - 1$. Therefore,
$$
|\rho^*| + c = n
$$
and thus
$$ |\rho^*| + |m^*| \geq |\rho^*| + c = n \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
Combinging $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$, we obtain
$$
|\rho^*| + |m^*| = n
$$

Comment: Could you explain why is it true the inequality $|m^∗|+|ρ^∗|≤|m^∗|+|ρ′|$  while proving $|ρ^∗|+|m^∗|\leq n$?

Comment: I think i am not getting it right because for instance, at [this graph](http://imgur.com/bkNawKY) you have $M^∗ = \{(0, 1), (3, 2)\}$ and $P^∗ = \{(0,1), (1,2),(2,3)\}$ and $S = M^∗$ so the inequality yields $2 + 3 \leq 2 + 2$ which is false.

Comment: @jscherman This is just because $\rho^*$ is a minimum edge cover, while $\rho'$ is some edge cover.

Answer (score 4):

I'm proposing an alternative proof, which may offer some new perspectives.

We traditionally denote the number of vertices by $n$, the edge covering number by $\beta'$, and the matching number by $\alpha'$. The goal is to prove the identity:

> **Theorem:** for any graph $G$ without isolated vertices: $\alpha' + \beta' = n$

We'll use the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** any minimum edge covering contains a maximum matching.

**Note:** the Lemma doesn't come out of nowhere - it's suggested by the theorem we try to prove. Indeed, viewed as a spanning subgraph of $G$, a minimum edge covering has the same $n$ and $\beta'$ as $G$, and would therefore have the same $\alpha'$.

**Proof of the Lemma:** Let $F$ a minimum edge covering of a graph $G$ (thus $|F| = \beta'$), $H$ the spanning subgraph of $G$ with edge set $F$, and $M$ a maximum matching of $H$ (thus also a matching of $G$).

Observe that $H$ has a very constrained edge structure: any edge of $H$ is either in $M$, or joins a matched vertex $s$ to an unmatched vertext $u$ (and is the only edge incident to $u$). Indeed, an edge $e \in F \setminus M$ cannot join two matched vertices (as $F$ would not be a minimum edge covering) and cannot join two unmatched vertices (as $M$ would not be a maximum matching)

Assume by way of contradiction that $M$ is not a maximum matching of $G$. By [Berge's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berge%27s_lemma), $G$ has an $M$-augmenting path $P$, of odd length $2k + 1$. We construct a new edge covering $F'$ from $F$, by:

1. Removing the $k$ edges of $M \cap P$
2. Removing the 2 edges covering the ends of $P$ (as observed above, since the ends of $P$ are unmatched by $M$, each one is covered by exactly one edge joining it to a matched vertex)
3. Adding at most $k + 1$ edges from $P \setminus M$ (those edges which are not already in $F. This covers any vertex which may have been uncovered by the previous removals.

$F'$ is an edge covering with $|F'| < |F|$, contradicting the choice of $F$.

**Proof of the Theorem:** As above, let $F$ a minimum edge covering of $G$ (thus $|F| = \beta'$), $H$ the spanning subgraph of $G$ with edge set $F$, and $M$ a maximum matching of $G$ contained in $F$ as per the Lemma (thus $|M| = \alpha'$). Let $U$ the set of unmatched vertices.

Decomposing $F$, and recalling the observation about the edge structure of $H$, we get

$$
|F| = \beta' = |M| + |F \setminus M| = |M| + |U| = \alpha' + |U| \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Decomposing the vertex set of $G$ into matched and unmatched vertices, we get:

$$
n = 2|M| + |U| = 2\alpha' + |U| \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Subtracting $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{1}$:

$$
\alpha' = n - \beta'
$$