# Connected Bigraph with $p$ vertices with Minimal Edge cover with $n$ edges and maximal matching with $m$ edges has $m+n=p$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected bigraph with $p$ vertices for $p>1$. Assume that a minimal edge cover $E$ of $G$ contains $n$ edges and a maximal matching $M$ of $G$ contains $m$ edges. Show that $m+n=p$.

I found the first half of this proof on my own: [Prove that the sum of minimum edge cover and maximum matching is the vertex count](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187560/prove-that-the-sum-of-minimum-edge-cover-and-maximum-matching-is-the-vertex-coun)

Couldn't manage the $\geq$ part though. The accepted answer is probably the expected solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the part of the bipartition with more vertices, and let B be the other part, so that there are only edges between A and B (note that possibly |A|=|B|. Since the graph is connected, there must be an edge adjacent to every vertex in B, so n=|B|. Now we want to show that |A|=m (notice that m cannot be bigger than the size of A). Suppose there is some vertex in A that is not covered by a maximal matching. Then there must also be some vertex in B which isn't covered since B is larger than A. Since the graph is connected, there must be a path between these two vertices that alternates between vertices in A and vertices in B. Swapping the edges in the matching with those that are not in the matching creates a bigger matching. So we can eventually get a matching with size m. Thus p=|A|+|B|=m+n.

Comment: Thanks. While this was clearly how I was supposed to complete the problem, I found this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187560/prove-that-the-sum-of-minimum-edge-cover-and-maximum-matching-is-the-vertex-coun) for the general case which is correct and well written unlike the proof in the MIT pdf here: https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18453S17/ps1_solutions.pdf

Comment: This is false $|B| \neq n$. Consider a graph where you have 2 star graphs joined at end vertices by 1 edge.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's not a counter-example

Comment: I should have said joined by a common edge from their root vertices, otherwise the graph wouldn't have still been a bigraph, my mistake; however, here's a picture. The minimal edge cover clearly has more than the number of vertices in either half. https://imgur.com/a/fnzMP4o